# JSONAPI serialize nested hasMany relationships

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, json-api

We're using JSONAPI for this project, but for [reasons] we can't handle its recommended relationship structure in the API, so we're serving and expecting them as nested objects instead, with the following format:

```
{
  "data":{
    "type":"video",
    "id":"55532284a1f9f909b0d11d73",

    "attributes":{
      "title":"Test",

      "transcriptions":{
        "type": "embedded",

        "data":[
          {
            "type":"transcription",
            "id":"203dee25-4431-42d1-a0ba-b26ea6938e75",

            "attributes":{
              "transcriptText":"Some transcription text here. And another sentence after it.",

              "cuepoints":{
                "type":"embedded",

                "data":[
                  {
                    "type":"cuepoint",
                    "id":"bb6b0434-bdc4-43e4-8010-66bdef5c432a",

                    "attributes":{
                      "text":"Some transcription text here."
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "type":"cuepoint",
                    "id":"b663ee00-0ebc-4cf4-96fc-04d904bc1baf",

                    "attributes":{
                      "text":"And another sentence after it."
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have the following model structure:

```
// models/video
export default DS.Model.extend({
  transcriptions: DS.hasMany('transcription')
)};

// models/transcription
export default DS.Model.extend({
  video: DS.belongsTo('video'),
  cuepoints: DS.hasMany('cuepoint')
});

// models/cuepoint
export default DS.Model.extend({
  transcription: DS.belongsTo('transcription')
);
```

Now, what we want to do is save a `video` record, and have it serialize the `transcriptions` and `cuepoints` it contains. I have the following serializer, and it works absolutely fine for embedding a `transcription` into a `video` ie. one level, but I need it to then embed the `cuepoints` into that too.

```
export default DS.JSONAPISerializer.extend({
    serializeHasMany: function(record, json, relationship) {
      var hasManyRecords, key;
          key = relationship.key;
          hasManyRecords = Ember.get(record, key);

      if (hasManyRecords) {
        json.attributes[key] = {};

        hasManyRecords.forEach(function(item) {
          json.attributes[key].data = json.attributes[key].data || [];

          json.attributes[key].data.push({
            attributes: item._attributes,
            id: item.get('id'),
            type: item.get('type')
          });
        });
      } else {
        this._super(record, json, relationship);
      }
    }
  });
```

Inspecting the `record`, `json` and `relationship` properties in the `serializeHasMany` method, I can't see anything about the nested relationships, so not even sure I'm using the right method.

Any ideas where I'm going wrong with this?

Comment: Have you looked into how EmbeddedRecordsMixin works? Might provide some inspiration on how to proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've figured this out. There were a few methods I didn't know existed for looping through relationships, and I needed to write a custom `serialize` method, instead of just overriding the default `serializeHasMany` one.

```
serialize(record) {
  // Set up the main data structure for the record to be serialized
  var JSON = {
    data: {
      id: record.id,
      type: record.modelName,
      attributes: {}
    }
  };

  // Find relationships in the record and serialize them into the JSON.data.attributes object
  JSON.data.attributes = this.serializeRelationships(JSON.data.attributes, record);

  // Loop through the record's attributes and insert them into the JSON.data.attributes object
  record.eachAttribute((attr) => {
    JSON.data.attributes[attr] = record.attr(attr);
  });

  // Return the fully serialized JSON data
  return JSON;
},

// Take a parent JSON object and an individual record, loops through any relationships in the record, and creates a JSONAPI resource object
serializeRelationships(JSON, record) {
  record.eachRelationship((key, relationship) => {
    if (relationship.kind === 'hasMany') {

      // Set up the relationship data structure
      JSON[relationship.key] = {
        data: []
      };

      // Gran any relationships in the record
      var embeddedRecords = record.hasMany(relationship.key);

      // Loop through the relationship's records and build a resource object
      if (embeddedRecords) {
        embeddedRecords.forEach((embeddedRecord) => {
          var obj = {
            id: embeddedRecord.id,
            type: embeddedRecord.modelName,
            attributes: {}
          }

          // Recursively check for relationships in the record
          obj.attributes = this.serializeRelationships(obj.attributes, embeddedRecord);

          // Loop through the standard attributes and populate the record.data.attributes object
          embeddedRecord.eachAttribute((attr) => {
            obj.attributes[attr] = embeddedRecord.attr(attr);
          });

          JSON[relationship.key].data.push(obj);
        });
      }
    }
  });

  return JSON;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add serializers for each of your models and tweak payloads in right serializer as needed. The serializers above produce the exact payload you provided in the description.

**app/serializers/cuepoint.js**

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.JSONAPISerializer.extend({

    payloadKeyFromModelName (modelName) {
        return modelName;
    },

    serialize (record, options) {
        return this._super(record, options).data;
    },

    serializeBelongsTo () {}

});
```

**app/serializers/transcription.js**

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.JSONAPISerializer.extend(DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin, {

    attrs: {
        cuepoints: {
            serialize: 'records',
            deserialize: 'records'
        }
    },

    keyForAttribute (key, method) {
        return key;
    },

    payloadKeyFromModelName (modelName) {
        return modelName;
    },

    serialize (record, options) {
        let json = this._super(record, options);
        json.data.attributes.cuepoints = {
            type: 'embedded',
            data: json.data.cuepoints
        }
        delete json.data.cuepoints;
        return json.data;
    },

    serializeBelongsTo () {}

});
```

**app/serializers/video.js**

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.JSONAPISerializer.extend(DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin, {

    attrs: {
        transcriptions: {
            serialize: 'records',
            deserialize: 'records'
        }
    },

    payloadKeyFromModelName (modelName) {
        return modelName;
    },

    serialize (record, options) {
        let json = this._super(record, options);
        json.data.attributes.transcriptions = {
            type: 'embedded',
            data: json.data.transcriptions
        }
        delete json.data.transcriptions;
        return json;
    },

    serializeBelongsTo () {}

});
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there no way to do this in a generic way then? I was really hoping I'd be able to recursive loop through relationships within the `serializeHasMany` method, but it looks like that's not possible.

Comment: @MalabarFront This is semanthically wrong. Why should video serializer know how to serialize transcription? Each model should be serialized by its own serializer. And this is how Ember works. You shouldn't try to hack it (even by accessing private properties and methods) since it could cause huge problems during update.

Comment: Because our API and data structure is very strict, the shape of all data — nested or not — is known. For this reason, I felt that writing a serializer for every model was nuts. I was hoping to write a serializer that would know how to handle nested data regardless of what the model was called.